# Not set cookie overwriting method parameter

Tags: php

So, I have a method that converts the timezone into another:

```
public function timeZoneConverter($from, $to = "America/New_York", $outputformat){
        $time = new DateTime($from, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
        $time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($to));
        return $time->format($outputformat);
    }
```

I give the `$to` parameter value from a cookie like this:

```
$calendar->timeZoneConverter($episode->air_date, $_COOKIE['timezone'], "Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

But if the cookie is not set, the `$to` parameter returns NULL, although I set "America/New_York" to default

Why? Is the null value of the cookie overwriting it? I can hard code it like this:

```
if($to == null){
   $to = "America/New_York";
}
```

But this seems kinda stupid.

Comment: did you try dumping the cookie value? sometimes the cookie remains and is an empty string instead of null, so try `if($to == null || $to == "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you'd have to do. Passing `null` to an optional parameter will not cause PHP to fall back to the default value, it'll just use the passed `null`.

Besides, it doesn't make sense to put optional parameters in the middle of required parameters list. It's not possible to pass the required parameter `$outputformat` without passing some value to `$to`.

You could remove the default value, and use the short coalescing syntax for handling the `null` case:

```
$time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($to ?: 'America/New_York'));
```